# Looping in Creating PDF in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The function only work once. It does not loop at all.

Tweaking by changing the for looping parameter to just number and changing the position of the lines.

```
function PDFAbsensi() {
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

// Get active sheet.
var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('PRINT ABSENSI');

// Set the output filename.
var idkelompok = sourceSheet.getRange(2,36).getValues();
var namakelompok = sourceSheet.getRange(2,2).getValues();
var nomorkelompok = sourceSheet.getRange(2,3).getValues();
var pdfName = idkelompok + " - " + namakelompok + " " + nomorkelompok;

// export url
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sourceSpreadsheet.getId()+'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
+ '&gid='+sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('PRINT ABSENSI').getSheetId(); 

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token} });


var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
if (parents.hasNext()) {
var folder = parents.next();}
else {
folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();}

// Loop
var jumlahpdf = sourceSheet.getRange(5,36).getValue();
for (i=0;i<jumlahpdf;i++) {

var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName+'.pdf');

// delete pdf if already exists
var files = folder.getFilesByName(pdfName+'.pdf');
while (files.hasNext())

{files.next().setTrashed(true);}

// create pdf
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

return true;

// Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

// Add the number for looping function
var updatenomorkelompok = sourceSheet.getRange(2,36).setValue(idkelompok-(-1));}}
```

I expect the code to create multiple PDF files. As of now it only made one each time it runs.

Comment: What does `Logger.log(jumlahpdf)` return?

Comment: It should be number inside the cell

Comment: Yes - have you checked if it is returning the number you're expecting?

Comment: I did, also I have tried changing the limit directly to number and it still did not work. Then I suspect the problem is with the code i put inside to execute. I tried to  change them around. They keep making only one pdf.

Comment: You have a `return` in the middle of your `for` loop.

Comment: I am basically copy paste-ing the code to create this. Thus, I do not have the understanding what the return do. Could you suggest the change that is necessary?

Comment: Remove it, it's ending the loop as soon as it gets to that line of code.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've added an answer to explain this further with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You have `return true` in the middle of your `for` loop.

---

#### Explanation:

The `return` is ending the function completely on the first loop. This is expected behaviour, see below from [MDN `return` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

---

#### Example:

Below is a basic `for` loop that logs the value of `i` with every run:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

This logs every iteration as expected.

Here's an example with the return statement you're using (same `for` loop, but with `return true` inside):

```js
testReturn();

function testReturn() {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    return true;
  }
}
```

When this function is called, we get a log entry for 0 (the first run), but as we're `return`ing, the function execution is ended, hence why your script is only processing the first PDF.

---

- [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)